# O que faz version compare?

Tags: php

Estava lendo a respeito do [`version_compare()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.version-compare.php.) do PHP.

Ainda assim, não compreendi muito do assunto, poderiam me explicar um pouco mais sobre?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Definição

[`version_compare()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.version-compare.php) compara duas versões, representadas por *strings*, que estejam/sejam padronizadas pelo PHP.

```
version_compare($versao1 , $versao2);
```

#### Parâmetros

Os parâmetros para usar o `version_compare()` são bem simples:

- versão 1 - Primeiro número de versão.
- versão 2 - Segundo número de versão.
- operador (opcional) - Quando especificado será realizado um teste para um relacionamento específico.

`if (version_compare(phpversion(), "4.3.0", ">=")) {
        // versão do PHP maior que 4.3.0
    } else {
        // versão do PHP menor que 4.3.0
    }`

> Operadores que podem ser usados são: `<, lt, <=, le, >, gt, >=, ge, ==, =, eq, !=, <>, ne`.

#### Resultados

**Quando não é utilizado o operador**:

- -1 se a primeira versão for menor que a segunda, 0 se forem iguais e 1 se a segunda for menor que a primeira.

**Quando é utilizando o operador**:

- `TRUE` se a comparação for a especificada pelo operador, `FALSE` caso contrário.

---

Com padronizadas pelo PHP, [me refiro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10997482/php-version-compare-returns-1-when-comparing-5-2-and-5-2-0) ao fato de que ambas devem demonstrar mesmo formato que seja aprovado pelo PHP, por exemplo:

```
version_compare('5.2', '5.2.0'); // -1
```

Irá retornar `-1`, pois o `5.2.0` não está padronizado na comparação.

Entretanto a mesma comparação, feita de melhor maneira retorna o esperado:

```
version_compare('5.2.1', '5.2.0'); // 1
version_compare('5.2.0', '5.2.0'); // 0
version_compare('5.2.0', '5.2.1'); // -1
```